# Fields internationalization

Tags: grails, internationalization

I need to make an internationalized (English and Arabic) application in grails, but I am facing some problems, for instance I got a domain named Students got the below fields: 
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
class Students  
{  
  String firstName  
  String lastName  
}
```

In the views I want the above fields to be shown according to the language that the user selected in the welcome page.

I already made the part of language selection, but how the another part can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

They are several different ways to handle internationalization.

For example by creating a sub class to wrap your fields:

```
class StudentFields
{  
  String firstName  
  String lastName  
}
```

And then add 2 references (one for each locale):

```
class Students  
{  
  StudentFields english
  StudentFields arabic
}
```

Then you can access both languages using:

```
StudentsInstance.english.firstname
```

and

```
StudentsInstance.arabic.firstname
```

You can create a custom Tag to handle the logic (switching between english / arabic depending on the current locale) for your GSP.

Comment: this means there will be 2 columns in the DB one first name English and the other is first name Arabic right ? is there a recommended plugin to handle the fields internationalization ?

Comment: It will be stored in 2 differents tables. If you want to have 2 columns in the same table use GORM composition feature 'static embedded = ['english', 'arabic']. ' If you prefer you can use a plugin like this one http://grails.org/plugin/i18n-fields.

Comment: i found a useful link i think it will solve my issue http://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/grails-scaffolding-enums-and-i18n/